# Setting up the docker api - modification of docker.conf

Tags: docker, docker-api

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KHhk38gVe0) about setting up the docker remote api by Packt publishing.
In the video we are told to change the /etc/init/docker.conf file by adding `"-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker/sock"` to `DOCKER_OPTS=`. Then we have to restart docker for the changes to take effect.
However after I do all that, I still can't curl localhost at that port. Doing so returns:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl localhost:4243/_ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4243: Connection refused
```

I'm relativity new to docker, if somebody could help me out here I'd be very grateful.

Edit:
docker.conf

```
description "Docker daemon"

start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]
limit nofile 524288 1048576
limit nproc 524288 1048576

respawn

kill timeout 20

pre-start script
        # see also https://github.com/tianon/cgroupfs-mount/blob/master/cgroupfs-mount
        if grep -v '^#' /etc/fstab | grep -q cgroup \
                || [ ! -e /proc/cgroups ] \
                || [ ! -d /sys/fs/cgroup ]; then
                exit 0
        fi
        if ! mountpoint -q /sys/fs/cgroup; then
                mount -t tmpfs -o uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755 cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup
        fi
        (
                cd /sys/fs/cgroup
                for sys in $(awk '!/^#/ { if ($4 == 1) print $1 }' /proc/cgroups); do
                        mkdir -p $sys
                        if ! mountpoint -q $sys; then
                                if ! mount -n -t cgroup -o $sys cgroup $sys; then
                                        rmdir $sys || true
                                fi
                        fi
                done
        )
end script

script
        # modify these in /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB (/etc/default/docker)
        DOCKER=/usr/bin/$UPSTART_JOB
        DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        if [ -f /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB ]; then
                . /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB
        fi
        exec "$DOCKER" daemon $DOCKER_OPTS
end script

# Don't emit "started" event until docker.sock is ready.
# See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6647
post-start script
        DOCKER_OPTS=
        if [ -f /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB ]; then
"/etc/init/docker.conf" 60L, 1582C
```

EDIT2: Output of `ps aux | grep docker`

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ps aux | grep docker
root       858  0.2  4.2 401836 21504 ?        Ssl  06:12   0:00 /usr/bin/docker daemon --insecure-registry 11.22.33.44
:5000
vagrant   1694  0.0  0.1  10460   936 pts/0    S+   06:15   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

Comment: Can you show the whole line of the conf file please?

Comment: @Auzias I can do you one better. I added the whole config file. There is only one line where I added the option so there should be no confusion.

Comment: What does `ps aux|grep docker` output look like?

Comment: @Auzias just added it.

Comment: The option are not used to start the daemon. Are you using `systemd` or the `service` command line? Try to restart the daemon. Try also to find out if other conf file of Docker are present (`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` for `systemd`, `/etc/init/docker.conf` for `service`, or other)

Comment: @Auzias There was another docker configuration file I changed and forgot about `/etc/default/docker` where I set `DOCKER_OPTS=DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 11.22.33.44:5000"`. I only needed to add the new option there after a comma and it works. However now I have another question. Can I edit DOCKER_OPTS only in one place? What is DOCKER_OPTS? It would be nice to append to DOCKER_OPTS like to an environment variable. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: `DOCKER_OPTS` is the options you want your daemon docker running with. You are expected to use a single place to modify it. It is not a good idea to use it as and env var as it is supposed to be immutable.

Comment: @Auzias I can live with that, just thought it would be convenient. Would you like to condense this comments into an answer, or should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

According to the output of `ps aux|grep docker` it can be noticed that the options the daemon is started with do not match the ones in the `docker.conf` file. Another file is then used to start the docker daemon service.

#### Solution

To solve this, track down the file that contains the option `"--insecure-registry 11.22.33.44:5000` that may either `/etc/default/docker` or `/etc/init/docker.conf` or `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` or idk-where-else and modify it accordingly with the needed options.

Then restart the daemon and you're good to go !